# An error in a subquery returns all data for a query

Tags: sql, postgresql, subquery, where-clause, correlated-subquery

I have the following data structure:

User:

- id
- name
- status_id

Post:

- id
- title
- user_id

The following query returns all blog rows

```
select * from Post where user_id in (select user_id from User where status_id = 7);
```

Although the subquery

```
select user_id from User where status_id = 7
```

is erroneous and if executed separately, it returns an error "ERROR: column "user_id" does not exist". What causes this behavior?

Comment: Tip of today: Qualify all columns!

Comment: You are actually doing `... in (select post.user_id from User...`...

Comment: of course it will give you error because the user_id is not in User table the column name is id check  it. this may work for you select * from Post where user_id in (select id from User where status_id = 7);

Answer (score 1):

> What causes this behavior?

The visibility rules for identifiers in sub-queries defined by the SQL standard mandate, that if the sub-query uses columns that are to available in any of the tables of the sub-query, that column refers to a column of the direct "parent" query.

This is a strange rule, but that's the way it's supposed to work.

This behaviour is one of the reasons, why it's highly recommended to qualify all column references with the table (alias) they belong to.

Comment: it might be good to example an alias; `SELECT a.column, b.another_column FROM a LEFT JOIN b ON....`

Comment: actually my example is MySQL; so may not be the correct syntax for postgre?

Answer (score 1):

There is no `user_id` column in `user`, so Postgres understands it as a reference to the `user_id` of `post`, which exists in both the outer scope and the subquery post: the filtering becomes a no-op, and returns all rows of `post` (as long as `user_id` is not `null`).

If you were to *qualify* the column names, you would get the error you expect:

```
select p.* 
from post p
where p.user_id in (select u.user_id from user u where u.status_id = 7);
```

Unrelated side note: I would phrase the query with `exists` instead:

```
select p.*
from post p
where exists (select 1 from user u where u.status_id = 7 and u.id = p.user_id)
```

This query would take advantage of an index on `user(id, status_id)`.

Answer (score 0):

Of course it will give you error because the user_id is not in User table the column is id check it.
Try this

```
 select * from Post where user_id in (select id from User where status_id = 7);
```